# Converting my bike to use quick release wheels

Tags: folding-bicycle

I have an activ folding bike designed by raleigh. I was wondering if I can swap the stock wheels for a wheel with a quick release? Or does the frame have to support it?

I also read I can use a quick release skewer but on their website it said that it's not suitable for bolt on hubs. How do I know if mine is a bolt on hub? It does look like it has a bolt going through it with a nut on either side.

Comment: It's a definite MAYBE.  You'd have to rebuild the "bolt on" hubs you have to replace the solid axles with hollow ones, or replace the wheels entirely.  You'd not have "lawyer lips".  And the existing axles may be oversize and QR wheels might not fit well, or there may be other reasons why the skewers will not clamp tightly enough on your frame.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, please post that as an answer instead of a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a definite MAYBE. You'd have to rebuild the "bolt on" hubs you have to replace the solid axles with hollow ones, or replace the wheels entirely. You'd not have "lawyer lips". And the existing axles may be oversize and QR wheels might not fit well, or there may be other reasons why the skewers will not clamp tightly enough on your frame.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is what diameter the axles are. If they are standard 10mm axles you will almost certainly be able to swap just the axles for hollow quick release ones. That's doable at home and easy for a bike shop (you need a flat "cone spanner" and preferably a vice). The only parts you need are front and rear QR axles and skewers plus new grease. I'd probably change the bearings and cones when I had it apart, depending on their condition. But you don't have to.

From looking at [this](https://www.bicyclerepairstation.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=158#prettyPhoto%5Bpp_gal%5D/11/) it seems to have fairly standard 20" wheels. From a mention in another search result I suspect it may have a 9mm diameter front axle which would make it tricky. It might be possible to fit a 10mm axle in there if you can find compatible cones - you need to either try it or find someone who has. But the rear wheel looks like a standard derailleur hub, so it should have a 10mm axle.

I suggest measuring the axle diameter as your first step. If they're both 10mm it'll be easy.

Comment: On some front hubs, you get 9mm axle. Don't forget that!